# How to get log4j message to show up in console for Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j

I have the following simple code, that i'm trying to run in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2016.3:

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Sample {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        log.info("This is a message");
    }
}
```

But i'm not able to see my message in the console and i'm get the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default   configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

I added all the jar files to the target directory. I thought using BasicConfigurator.configure() allows you to not use a config file.

Comment: See examples here - http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator

Comment: These examples are for the old EOL Log4j 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imports are for the old Log4j 1 library. 
For Log4j2, you need `org.apache.logging.log4j`.

Log4j2 has much better documentation than the old Log4j 1. Programmatic configuration is covered [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need a configuration file in your resources path. The default file name is `log4j2.yaml`. This is my way. And you need change you `import path`

Comment: Thank you! This is what I've been looking for